# Number of non negative integral solutions when the values of the variables are also bounded above.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, generating-functions

What is the number of non-negative integral solutions of the equation $x_1+ \cdots +x_n=d,$ where $0 \leq x_i \leq e_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots ,n$ for some positive integers $e_i.$

Without the upper bound of the indeterminates I know how to calculate it, infact in that case the answer is $n+d-1 \choose d$. I need some help to prove it. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: use the principle of inclusion-exclusion to count the number of "bad" solutions to $x_1+\dots+x_n=d$, $0\le x_i$, where _at least_ one variable $x_i>e_i$.